# element.classlist not working in client side

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. When i headed with the javascript events i have seen about `element.classList`.So i have tried out some code to understand how it works ..

The code i have done

```
var n = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
var c = n.classList.add('name');
console.log(c);
```

it gives me error like  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`.

Can anyone point me where am going wrong ??

Comment: `n` is a **list** of elements. `classList` is a property of a DOM element, not a *list* of DOM elements.

Comment: @FelixKling can you provide an answer with an example ..it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList (which is like an Array). Note that "Elements" is plural.

`classList` is a property of an Element (singular)

You need to loop over the Elements in the NodeList and access the `classList` property of each one in turn.

```
for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    console.log( n[i].classList.add('name') );
}
```

Comment: wow this was helpful ..classlist.add('somename'); is used to assign a class name to an element right ??